# Assign inputted date to a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have an app that makes a request through an API call, and returns the data.  I created two date methods (the request uses these dates as parameters), so that it always calls the data from last week:

```
def self.monday
  d = Date.today
  seven_days_ago = (d - 7)
  seven_days_ago.beginning_of_week
end


def self.sunday
  d = Date.today
  seven_days_ago = (d - 7)
  seven_days_ago.end_of_week
end
```

I would like to use these monday and sunday methods as the default values for the application, but if the user inputs dates in a form, these methods will be overwritten by the inputted values.  These inputted values should stay as the user is navigating the site, until there is a new session, or they clear the values (thus sending the methods back to their default values).

How would I create a form that doesn't save dates to a database, but just overwrites the default dates in the two methods above?  Then those dates should stay active until they clear that form, or they start a new session?

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.monday(options = {})
  if options[:date]
    return Date.parse(options[:date])
  else
    d = Date.today
    seven_days_ago = (d - 7)
    return seven_days_ago.beginning_of_week
end
```

**Will use default date**

```
whatever.monday()
```

**Will use specific date**

```
whatever.monday(:date => '2013-07-01')
```

Comment: How could I get the :date information to the method?  My form asks for two dates, :first_date, and :second_date.  :first_date would be wired to self.monday, and :second_date would go to self.sunday.